# Sharing typescript code between two projects in a monorepo (just the same as locally)

Tags: lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Iv been playing around with attempting to share code between two repos, so i understand the monorepo approach using lerna & yarn workspaces.

But take this example:
Lets say I have 2 react projects within a monorepo. And they share code, lets say they share:

`components, utils, modules, redux reducers/actions`

Why is it i cannot create a 'shared folder' and then be able to import these modules just like i would locally.

`import LoginComponent from '@shared/components/login/LoginComponent'`

---

From my understanding its not possible to do like the above? As you lose the folder structure from importing the @shared repo and have to export everything inside an index

So i guess i could add a package.json at the root of `@shared/*` but then i only have the one tier directory for structure.

It seems a little odd to not be able to simply be able to import from a shared directory between projects in a monorepo? Is this for any reason or am i missing something?

Or is there anything wrong with then importing the code like:

`import LoginComponent from '../../../shared/components/login/LoginComponent'`
?

Where shared will be within `/packages`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that actually. I have done it with react typescript project. You can check this implementation here. http://devwithabhi.com/setting-up-react-typescript-monorepo-with-lerna/